# <depends> doesn't work as expected in widget.xml in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, widget

So I'm trying to create dependent field, that would appear if the respective drop-down value will be chosen. My `widget.xml` looks like this:

```
<widgets xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Widget:etc/widget.xsd">
    <widget id="DemoWidget" class="Demo\DemoWidget\Block\Widget\Demo" placeholder_image="Demo_DemoWidget::logo.png">
        <label translate="true">Demo Widget</label>
        <description translate="true">Demo widget</description>
        <parameters>
            <parameter name="is_enabled" xsi:type="select" visible="true" sort_order="10">
                <label translate="true">Is Enabled?</label>
                <options>
                    <option name="1" value="1">
                        <label>Yes</label>
                    </option>
                    <option name="0" value="0">
                        <label>No</label>
                    </option>
                </options>
            </parameter>
            <parameter name="link_url" xsi:type="block" visible="true" sort_order="20">
                <label translate="true">Link URL</label>
                <block class="Demo\DemoWidget\Block\Adminhtml\Widget\UrlInput"></block>
                <depends>
                    <parameter name="is_enabled" value="1"></parameter>
                </depends>
            </parameter>
        </parameters>
    </widget>
</widgets>
```

Of course, it doesn't work - I see both drop-down and block input, but changing the drop-down doesn't work at all. I was trying to find a solution, and [this one](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176091/magento-2-depends-is-not-working-in-widget-xml) seemed to be very promising. However, after I implemented it, the admin panel shows me this error:
`Element 'depends': This element is not expected.`

It wasn't the case before I followed the instruction from the above mentioned solution, so I assume it worked in a certain way. However, as far as I know, `<depends>` should be possible to use in `widget.xml`, so I'm very lost. Does anyone have any solution/ideas on how to fix that?

My `requirejs-config.js`, which is located ad `DemoWidget/view/adminhtml/web`(I also tried to move it to `adminhtml` folder, used a couple of versions of path to form, didn;t work):

```
var config = {
    map: {
        "*": {
            "mage/adminhtml/form": "DemoWidget/view/adminhtml/web/js/form"
        }
    }
};
```

And this is the `trackChange()` I used instead of original one in `DemoWidget/view/adminhtml/web/js/form.js` file:

```
trackChange : function(e, idTo, valuesFrom)
         {
             // define whether the target should show up
             var shouldShowUp = true;
             for (var idFrom in valuesFrom) {
                 var from = $(idFrom);
                 if (from) {
                     var values = valuesFrom[idFrom]['values'];
                     var isInArray = values.indexOf(from.value) != -1;
                     var isNegative = valuesFrom[idFrom]['negative'];
                     if (!from || isInArray && isNegative || !isInArray && !isNegative) {
                         shouldShowUp = false;
                     }
                 }
             }
     
             // toggle target row
             var headElement = $(idTo + '-head'),
                 isInheritCheckboxChecked = $(idTo + '_inherit') && $(idTo + '_inherit').checked,
                 target = $(idTo);
     
             // Custom code to account for the chooser style parameters.
             if (target === null && headElement === null && idTo.substring(0, 16) === 'options_fieldset') {
                 headElement = jQuery('.field-' + idTo).add('.field-chooser' + idTo);
             }
     
             // Target won't always exist (for example, if field type is "label")
             if (target) {
                 var inputs = target.up(this._config.levels_up).select('input', 'select', 'td'),
                     isAnInputOrSelect = ['input', 'select'].indexOf(target.tagName.toLowerCase()) != -1;
             } else {
                 var inputs = false,
                     isAnInputOrSelect = false;
             }
             if (shouldShowUp) {
                 var currentConfig = this._config;
                 if (inputs) {
                     inputs.each(function (item) {
                         // don't touch hidden inputs (and Use Default inputs too), bc they may have custom logic
                         if ((!item.type || item.type != 'hidden') && !($(item.id+'_inherit') && $(item.id+'_inherit').checked)
                             && !(currentConfig.can_edit_price != undefined && !currentConfig.can_edit_price)) {
                             item.disabled = false;
                             jQuery(item).removeClass('ignore-validate');
                         }
                     });
                 }
                 if (headElement) {
                     headElement.show();
                     if (target && headElement.hasClassName('open')) {
                         target.show();
                     } else if (target) {
                         target.hide();
                     }
                 } else {
                     if (target) {
                         target.show();
                     }
                     if (isAnInputOrSelect && !isInheritCheckboxChecked) {
                         if (target) {
                             target.disabled = false;
                         }
                         jQuery('#' + idTo).removeClass('ignore-validate');
                     }
                 }
             } else {
                 if (inputs) {
                     inputs.each(function (item){
                         // don't touch hidden inputs (and Use Default inputs too), bc they may have custom logic
                         if ((!item.type || item.type != 'hidden') && !($(item.id+'_inherit') && $(item.id+'_inherit').checked)) {
                             item.disabled = true;
                             jQuery(item).addClass('ignore-validate');
                         }
                     });
                 }
                 if (headElement) {
                     headElement.hide();
                 }
                 if (target) {
                     target.hide();
                 }
                 if (isAnInputOrSelect && !isInheritCheckboxChecked) {
                     if (target) {
                         target.disabled = true;
                     }
                     jQuery('#' + idTo).addClass('ignore-validate');
                 }
     
             }
             var rowElement = $('row_' + idTo);
             if (rowElement == undefined && target) {
                 rowElement = target.up(this._config.levels_up);
             }
             if (rowElement) {
                 if (shouldShowUp) {
                     rowElement.show();
                 } else {
                     rowElement.hide();
                 }
             }
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked it on Magento 2.4.3 and additionally I had to move `depends` element above the `block` element.

From vendor\magento\module-widget\etc\widget.xsd there is defined sequence (around lines 63-79)

```
 <xs:complexType name="parameterType" abstract="true">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>
            Abstract type which is parent of all parameters. Contains attributes
            and elements common across all parameter types.
        </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="label" type="translatableType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="description" type="translatableType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="depends" type="dependsType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:NMTOKEN" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="visible" type="xs:boolean" />
    <xs:attribute name="sort_order" type="xs:int" />
    <xs:attribute name="required" type="xs:string" />
</xs:complexType>
```

That is why the admin shows the error:

> Element 'depends': This element is not expected.

Further in schema file there is `block` element, defined by this fragment (around 91-102 lines) :

```
<xs:complexType name="block">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Parameter type which supplies a renderer.</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="parameterType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="block" type="blockType" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

So we need to arrange the elements in a specific order. Element `depends` has to be before the `block` element.

Here is my solution without using `source_model` attribute (check Rahul Barot's example). I added attribute `selected` for `option` element:

```
<widgets xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Widget:etc/widget.xsd">
<widget id="DemoWidget" class="Demo\DemoWidget\Block\Widget\Demo" placeholder_image="Demo_DemoWidget::logo.png">
    <label translate="true">Demo Widget</label>
    <description translate="true">Demo widget</description>
    <parameters>
        <parameter name="is_enabled" xsi:type="select" visible="true" sort_order="10">
            <label translate="true">Is Enabled?</label>
            <options>
                <option name="1" value="1">
                    <label>Yes</label>
                </option>
                <option name="0" value="0" selected="true">
                    <label>No</label>
                </option>
            </options>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="cms_chooser" xsi:type="block" visible="true" sort_order="20">
            <label translate="true">Cms Block</label>
            <depends>
                <parameter name="is_enabled" value="1"/>
            </depends>
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Chooser"/>
        </parameter>
    </parameters>
</widget>
```

That's all. No need for additional js code.
In this example, I used the existing block in Magento.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was really detailed and helpful - I did as instructed, and it worked immediately :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below widget.xml and let me know if it works for you. I've changed the select dropdown code to use the source model.

```
<widgets xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Widget:etc/widget.xsd">
<widget id="DemoWidget" class="Demo\DemoWidget\Block\Widget\Demo" placeholder_image="Demo_DemoWidget::logo.png">
        <label translate="true">Demo Widget</label>
        <description translate="true">Demo widget</description>
        <parameters>
            <parameter name="is_enabled" xsi:type="select" visible="true" sort_order="10"
                source_model="Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno">
                <label translate="true">Is Enabled?</label>
            </parameter>
            <parameter name="link_url" xsi:type="block" visible="true" sort_order="20">
                <label translate="true">Link URL</label>
                <depends>
                    <parameter name="is_enabled" value="1"></parameter>
                </depends>
                <block class="Demo\DemoWidget\Block\Adminhtml\Widget\UrlInput"></block>
            </parameter>
        </parameters>
    </widget>
</widgets>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate your effort to help! Unfortunately, I can't upvote your answer since I don't have 15 reputation so far, but I will come back to it once I'll have it!